# Problems inserting a formula in excel through vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In excel I am trying to insert the following formula into a cell through VBA, but I get the error

> "Application-defined or obkect-defined error"

The formula I am trying is

```
formula_bus = _
    "=VLOOKUP(H3,choose({2\1},[excelfile.xlsx]exceltab!$A$2:$A$13,[excelfile.xlsx]exceltab!$B$2:$B$13),2,FALSE)"
```

I think the error is in the {  }

The formula I am trying is

```
Sub Macro4()

 formula_bus = _
 "=VLOOKUP(H3,choose({2\1},[excelfile.xlsx]exceltab!$A$2:$A$13,[excelfile.xlsx]exceltab!$B$2:$B$13),2,FALSE)"

  Range("H12").Formula = formula_bus

End Sub
```

If I write this formula directly on Excel, works fine.  So I think is something with conversion from vba to Excel.

Comment: Try replacing the backslash in the array with a comma: `{2,1}` or just use INDEX/MATCH instead.

Comment: Easiest way to have "VBA" formula is. 
1. Put proper formula in excell cell. 
2 Start macro recorder. 
3 Edit formula in cell and confirm it (eg hit "F2" and "Enter"). 
4 Look for your formula in module. 
5 Copy formula to your code.

Comment: Rory, Thanks, your first solution was successful time.

Comment: Sphinx, Thank you too. Although I test the other solution first, your proposal was successful in a similar problem that I had recently.